# Image get corrupted while storing and retrieving it from database using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting problem while storing and retrieving image from MySQL database. I am able to save the image in MySQL database in following manner.

JSP Page(Multipart Object) -> byte[] in Service class -> SerialBlob in DAO class.

- From JSP page using EL and SpEL I passed image file in the form of Multipart object, and then in controller converted **multipart into byte[]**   and stored it inside the DTO and then pass that byte[] by converting it into **SerialBLOB**  in Service class and stored it into database using DAO. 
  It is working efficiently.
- To retrieve image from database, first I stored the retrieved image in the the form of BLOB object and then converted it into byte[], but to view the image into JSP I had to convert byte[]] into String format. It is working when I have created two different projects for storing and retrieving images.
- But, the problem came when I tried to do both storing and retrieving image from database, for that I had to change my DTO's image property return type into String because I had to pass String into my JSP page to view image. Here, retrieving worked fine but when I tried to store the image file when converting multipart into string and string into ( string -> byte[ ] -> SerialBLOB ) SerialBLOB it stored into the database but the image get corrupted, it say's **invalid image** when open.

### Controller Snippet:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String productsPageInsert(Map<String, Object> map, @Valid 
    @ModelAttribute("productCmd") ProductsCommand productsCommand, 
    BindingResult errors) throws IOException {

      List<ProductLinksDTO> listLinksDTO = null;
      ProductLinksDTO linkDTO1 = null, linkDTO2 = null;
      ProductsDTO productsDTO = null;
      List<ProductsDTO> listDTO = null;
      String result = null;

      try {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "adminProductsDef";
        }
        listLinksDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        listDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        linkDTO1 = new ProductLinksDTO();
        linkDTO2 = new ProductLinksDTO();
        productsDTO = new ProductsDTO();

        // Adding links to list
        linkDTO1.setLink(productsCommand.getLinkFirst());
        linkDTO2.setLink(productsCommand.getLinkSecond());
        listLinksDTO.add(linkDTO1);
        listLinksDTO.add(linkDTO2);

        // Adding data into dto
        productsDTO.setProductName(productsCommand.getProductName());
        productsDTO.setDescription(productsCommand.getDescription());
        productsDTO.setLinks(listLinksDTO);

        // adding image into products dto.
        productsDTO.setImage(new String(productsCommand.getImage().getBytes()));

        listDTO.add(productsDTO);

        result = productsService.addProduct(productsDTO);
        map.put("resultMsg", result);
        map.put("products", listDTO);

        return "redirect: /home_page/products_page.htm";
        } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
        map.put("errorMsg", dae.getMessage() + "\n" + dae.getStackTrace());
        return "failure";
        } catch (SerialException e) {
        map.put("errorMsg", e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace());
        return "failure";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        map.put("errorMsg", e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace());
        return "failure";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        map.put("errorMsg", e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getStackTrace());
        return "failure";
        }
   }
```

- When I was converting Multipart object file into String it must get corrupted.

### Service class snippet

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String addProduct(ProductsDTO productsDTO) throws SerialException, SQLException {
    int count = 0;
    ProductsHLO productsHLO = null;

    List<ProductLinksHLO> listLinkHLO = new ArrayList<>();
    productsHLO = new ProductsHLO();

    // copy dto data into hlo

        productsDTO.getLinks().forEach(linkDTO -> {
        ProductLinksHLO linkHLO = new ProductLinksHLO();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(linkDTO, linkHLO);
        listLinkHLO.add(linkHLO);
    });

    productsHLO.setDescription(productsDTO.getDescription());

    // converting (image) String into SerialBlob  
    productsHLO.setImage(new SerialBlob(productsDTO.getImage().getBytes()));

    productsHLO.setProductName(productsDTO.getProductName());
    productsHLO.setLinks(listLinkHLO);

    // executing dao method
    count = productsDAO.insertProduct(productsHLO);
    if (count != 0)
        return "Product added successfully";
    else
        return "Product Not added!";
}
```

Please help me and give me any suggestion so this won't happen. If you have any other idea for this operation then please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: When you write "it says invalid image when open", what is the `it`?

Comment: Sorry for poor english. After image stored inside the database, when I save it externally from database and tried to open it, that time its says. "invalid image."